# Can't find mscomctllib in add reference

Tags: c#, .net, com, vb6

I believe this could be fairly simple to figure out, but I have been trying to for the past few hours in vain and everywhere in the net seems to point me back to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963442/warning-msb3283-cannot-find-wrapper-assembly-for-type-library-mscomctllib-wh)

I get exactly the same error: 
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1558,9): warning MSB3283: Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "MSComctlLib".
========== Build: 7 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

I try to remove and re-add the dependency to fix,but the problem is that I don't find mscomctllib when I go to add reference (com tab).
Am I missing something here? Or am I looking for the wrong thing?
Am running VS 2010 and converting the app from .net 2.0 to 4.0.

Comment: Why is this tagged C# and VB6?

Comment: Taking a dependency on this VB6 component is very unwise.  Security updates have been [quite unkind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13017139/17034) to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're in the COM tab under References, look for "Microsoft Windows Common Controls" or similar. Here it is on my system (Windows 7 / VS2012):

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This worked like charm. I had intepreted MSComCtlLib as Microsoft Component Control and was looking for that instead. Thanks, saved my day.

Comment: what about for windows 10 VS2012 old projects? thanks

Comment: @Grant Hello, I installed VS2005 for some old dependencies too lol. I got the file from a work mate computer, then I did a regsvr32.exe to the mscomctl.ocx and installed the lib (so now was visible for VS2012). I hate legacy projects... Thanks for the reply anyway!!!! I really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 7 it's in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and it's an OCX not a DLL  so in VS, when you go to add references, click on the browse button and look around there.

Comment: Thanks for the response and for pointing out its an ocx.But i added reference like below and it worked. However, I found MSComctl.ocx at that location. Is that supposed to be the same thing as MSComctllib?